# Facebook PHP applications: restrict access only to some users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to restrict access to my facebook php application only to some users. The only way I find is something like this:

```
.
.
.
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id == 123456789) {
  //OK!
}
else {
  //NOT OK!
}
.
.
.
```

Is there a better way?
Is there a way in the developpers panel of facebook?
Thank you!

Comment: You could make the app not public, and add only those users as testers (but then everything the app posts etc. will be only visible to them as well).

Comment: How I can make the app not public?

Comment: “Status & Review” page in app settings.